# Is it better to use git branch -f or git update-ref to fast-forward existing branch?

Tags: git

I have realized that I can use [`git update-ref` to fast-forward existing branch that I am not on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737637/). Then I have found that similar thing can be done by `git branch -f`. I understand that `git update-ref` is much more flexible (it can move any ref), [however it could be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26745515/121968). So is it better to use `git branch -f`? Are there any differences in these two commands in this particular scenarios? (Except of that I can specify custom ref log message.)

Comment: FYI: Even with `update-ref` there is no real danger of losing commits, as described in the answer you linked to. The commits will be still there and you can stil easily recover them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`git branch -f`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), it would refuse to update the branch if it is the one checked out (so if it is the "current branch")

[`git update-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref) has not that limitation.

---

[Qqwy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067339/qqwy) adds another difference [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752567/is-it-better-to-use-git-branch-f-or-git-update-ref-to-fast-forware-existing-bra/26752608#comment54446300_26752608):

- `git branch -f  <branchname> [<start-point>]` will create a new branch called `<branchname>` if it did not exist.
- `git update-ref <branchname> <newvalue>` will do nothing in this case.

Comment: It seems like `update-ref` doesn't provide the same autocomplete features `branch -f` does. Is it possible to change git's behaviour to create the same experience for `update-ref`?

Comment: @Zeeker that would be a good separate question: I haven't look too much in the autocompletion part of those commands.

Comment: I've asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798130/expand-gits-autocomplete-feature-to-plumbing-commands).