# Expand git's autocomplete feature to plumbing commands

Tags: git, autocomplete, git-plumbing

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752567/is-it-better-to-use-git-branch-f-or-git-update-ref-to-fast-forware-existing-bra), I asked myself if it would be possible to tell git to provide it's autocomplete feature (branches etc.) for further commands, in particular plumbing commands like `update-ref`.

Although `update-ref` provides more flexibility than `branch -f`, it's quite a hassle to use since you always have to type the full reference name. Which in turn doesn't make me want to use it.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: You are talking about the git-completion shell script?

Comment: @AndrewC I assume I am.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to enable the plumbing commands but you will need to provide some of the implementation yourself.

Find the `git-completion.sh` script you are using.

In my `/users/andrewc/.bashrc` I have

```
# GIT STUFF 
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ] 
then
    . ~/.git-completion.bash 
fi
```

So I pull up `/users/andrewc/git-completion.bash`

Find the function `__git_list_porcelain_command())` and comment out the line for  `update-ref`

```
        #update-ref)       : plumbing;;
```

This will allow `update-ref` itself to autocomplete.  The script won't know how to fill in any of the args to `update-ref` though.  It looks like you will need to provide an implementation for `__git_update_ref` to achieve this.  I would use a similar command (`__git_branch maybe) as a template and go from there.